# What is the longest you can susbcribe to change to an attribute?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

So i'm working on a project that requires for cygnus to subscribe to an attribute for at least 2 or 3 months. The longest time i have found to work was 1 month using "P1M". Is there any way to extend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert on Orion (I'm the main develop or Cygnus :)) but AFAIK you can subscribe for years. You can found this at [readthedocs](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#context-subscriptions):

> Subscriptions have a duration, specified using the ISO 8601 standard format. Once that duration is expired, the subscription is simply ignored (however, it is still stored in the broker database and needs to be purged using the procedure described in the administration manual). You can extend the duration of a subscription by updating it, as described later in this document. We are using "P1M" which means "one month".

The link to duration format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601